ValueError("Incoming message has no 'type' attribute") django channels
I wrote these codes with Django Channels, but it gives me an error:
These codes used to work correctly, but I don't know why they went wrong.
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message_type = text_data_json["type"]
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        if message_type == 'providerToAdmin':
            chat = Chats.objects.get(user=self.sender)
            Message.objects.create(text=message, date=datetime.datetime.now(), user_type=0, chat=chat)
            group_name = f'chat_{self.admin.username}'
            # self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'check': True, 'message': message}))
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                group_name, {"userType": 0, "data": message, 'chatId': chat.id}
            )

        if message_type == 'adminToUsers':
            chat = Chats.objects.get(user=self.sender)
            Message.objects.create(text=message, date=datetime.datetime.now(), user_type=1, chat=chat)
            group_name = f'chat_{self.admin.username}'
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                group_name, {"userType": 0, "data": message, 'chatId': chat.id}
            )

        if message_type == 'providerToStore':
            receiver = text_data_json["receiver"]
            receiver = Store.objects.get(user__username=receiver)
            provider = Provider.objects.get(user__username=self.sender)
            chat = ChatsSP.objects.get(store=receiver, provider=provider)
            MessageSP.objects.create(text=message, date=datetime.datetime.now(), user_type=1, chat=chat)
            group_name = f'chat_{receiver.user.username}'
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                group_name, {"userType": 0, "data": message, 'chatId': chat.id}
            )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["data"]
        name = event["name"]
        userName = event["userName"]
        chatId = event["chatId"]
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message, 'name': name, 'userName': userName,
                                        'chatId': chatId
                                        }))

but it raised this error:
aise ValueError("Incoming message has no 'type' attribute")


I encountered the same issue today, and after some debugging, I found the solution. The problem is that Channels expects a key called type in the message you're sending. This key is used to route the message to the correct handler within your consumer.
In your current code, you're passing a key like userType, but Channels doesn't recognize that key for routing purposes. Instead, you need to include a type key that maps to a method in your consumer.
Here's an example:
{"type": "providerToStore", "data": message, 'chatId': chat.id}

